# TypeError: settings.data is undefined in MOCKJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mockjax

I have mockjax code and it give me error.Here is my code

```
  $.mockjax({
    url: '*',
    responseTime: 2000,
    response: function (settings) {
        var query = settings.data.query,
            queryLowerCase = query.toLowerCase(),
            re = new RegExp('\\b' + $.Autocomplete.utils.escapeRegExChars(queryLowerCase), 'gi'),
            suggestions = $.grep(countriesArray, function (country) {
                 // return country.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryLowerCase) === 0;
                return re.test(country.value);
            }),
            response = {
                query: query,
                suggestions: suggestions
            };

        this.responseText = JSON.stringify(response);
    }
});
```

Here is my ajax code

```
 $.ajax({
             async: false,
             url: 'coments.php?id='+$('#id').val()+'&cmnt='+$('#cmnt').val()+'&type=2',
             success: function(data) {
             alert('saved');
             }
});
```

It give me error `TypeError: settings.data is undefined` when i check console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [documented bug in Mockjax](https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax/issues/123). Basically, the request matcher only works with data objects, not query strings. You could alter your `$.ajax()` call like so to match your mock:

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: 'coments.php',
    data: {
        id: $('#id').val(),
        cmnt: $('#cmnt').val(),
        type: 2
    }
    success: function(data) {
        alert('saved');
    }
});
```